# Some folders are not copied when build image with docker build for asp.net core web application

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have following dockerfile content

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Nuget.config", "."]
COPY ["MyProject/MyProject.csproj", "MyProject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" --configfile /src/Nuget.config
COPY . .

WORKDIR /src/MyProject
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build --configfile /src/Nuget.config

RUN mkdir -p /app/publish/MyNotes
RUN mkdir -p /app/publish/MyData
RUN cp -R "../packages/mylibrary/2.0.3/lib/netstandard2.0/MyNotes" "/app/publish/"
RUN cp -R "../packages/mylibrary/2.0.3/lib/netstandard2.0/MyData" "/app/publish/"

#COPY ["../packages/mylibrary/2.0.3/lib/netstandard2.0/MyNotes", "/app/publish/MyNotes"]
#COPY ["../packages/mylibrary/2.0.3/lib/netstandard2.0/MyNotes/ps/", "/app/publish/MyNotes/ps/"]
#COPY ["../packages/mylibrary/2.0.3/lib/netstandard2.0/MyNotes/pc/", "/app/publish/MyNotes/pc/"]
#COPY ["../packages/mylibrary/2.0.3/lib/netstandard2.0/MyData", "/app/publish/MyData"]

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish --no-restore

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN find . -type f
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

I want to copy some files from packages folder to build folder.

The structure of MyNotes and MyData:

```
MyNotes
  |_ pc
      |_ example1.txt
      |_ example2.txt
  |_ ps
      |_ example4.txt

MyData
  |_ example7.txt
```

If I run `RUN find . -type f`, it seems that folders MyData and MyNotes are copied.

After compiled image, after I run docker image `docker run -d -p 8080:80 mycontainer` and then `docker exec -it GUID bash`, I run `ls` to see that `MyNotes` folder does not exist, but `MyData` is.

I don't understand why, where is my mistake ? I have same issue if I run COPY (see commented lines with # in front).

Comment: did u find a solution got the same thing